# Inaccessible Samba share with vscan-clamav

Tags: 10.04, server, samba, clamav

I have set up Samba with vscan-clamav and everything seems to be configured properly.  However, when I try to access a Samba share from Windows I get the following error.

```
---------------------------
Open Folder
---------------------------
\\<share name> is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.

A device attached to the system is not functioning.

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

When I comment out the following lines in smb.conf, I can access the shares but obviously the real-time virus scanning does not work.

```
vfs object = vscan-clamav
vscan-clamav: config-file = /etc/samba/vfs-config/vscan-clamav.conf
```

I have verified that clamav is running properly.  I've also verified the following:

vscan-clamav.conf contains `clamd socket name = /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl` which does exist.

The clamav user has ownership of the /var/run/clamav directory.

The clamav daemon is running.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Look in your system log, you might see messages like this:

```
smbd_vfs_init: vfs_init_custom failed for vscan-clamav
vfs_init failed for service x
```

If so this may indicate that you don't have the vscan-clamav pluggable module on your system. If you have it, you should find it as a directory (or maybe a file?) at `/usr/lib/samba` or `/usr/local/lib/samba`. You need this module as well as running clamav.